# Swagger not generating version 2 for the swagger.json using apiexplorer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using the api explorer to add versioning to my .net 5 web api project v1 shows up fine and is no issue but version 2 does not appear their to different controls not the same names nor methods. I am using .net 5 here.

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
 {              

   using (var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
   {
     var provider = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();
     String assemblyDescription = typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyDescriptionAttribute>().Description;

     foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
     {
        options.SwaggerDoc(description.GroupName, new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo()
        {
            Title = $"{typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyProductAttribute>().Product} {description.ApiVersion}",
            Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString() ,
            Description = description.IsDeprecated ? $"{assemblyDescription} - DEPRECATED" : $"{assemblyDescription}"

        });
    }
}

options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Description =
        "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 12345abcdef\"",
    Name = "Authorization",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
    Scheme = "Bearer"
});
options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "Bearer"
            },
            Scheme = "oauth2",
            Name = "Bearer",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header
        },
        new List<string>()
    }
});
var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var xmlDocs = currentAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()
.Union(new AssemblyName[] { currentAssembly.GetName() })
.Select(a => Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(currentAssembly.Location), $"{a.Name}.xml"))
.Where(f => File.Exists(f)).ToArray();

Array.ForEach(xmlDocs, (d) =>
{
    options.IncludeXmlComments(d);
});


options.DocumentFilter<RemoveDefaultApiVersionRouteDocumentFilter>();
options.OperationFilter<RemoveQueryApiVersionParamOperationFilter>();
```

You will see here that it does indeed work

[image]

Is My App Config section

```
app.UseSwagger();
var provider = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();
     
app.UseSwaggerUI(
    options =>
    {
        options.DocExpansion(Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.DocExpansion.None);
        // build a swagger endpoint for each discovered API version
        foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
            options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
    });
```

**Edit 2**
I found the issue was a controller method the same index :-( I must have missed it however its not opening the defualt version i have to use the dropdown to exapnd the docs is their anyway of exapnding it as default

By Expanding At Present it looks like this with version enabled when the user goes to it first. Where the action names are collapsed

[image]

But i want it to look like this where the actions name are expanded.

[image]

**Edit 3**
You need this line in your swagger ui to have them list i had it set to none.
This should be in your configure section.

```
 options.DocExpansion(Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.DocExpansion.List);
```

Comment: when the swagger reports errors, you can take a look in the `Output` window to see the detailed thrown exception there. It should say fairly clearly on the cause.

Comment: As I said I already cured this I in fact used the url of the json file and found my issue